# Maven Module Junit Test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have root projects and followed by sub modules. These modules are interdepended, When i run maven test for one module it throws class not found exception.

1. ProjectA 
   -- ProjectSubA 
   -- ProjectSubB 
   -- ProjectSubC (Dependencies ProjectA and ProjectB)

ProjectSubC has Maven Test, So when it runs the class are inside ProjectSubB and ProjectSubA. How to resolve this issue now.

Comment: If your modules are interdepended than you can simply call from root `mvn clean test` and this should work...If not fix your tests.

Comment: see my answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244265/run-junit-tests-for-maven-reactor-nested-sub-sub-module/49596611#49596611

Answer (score 0):

1. change to the root project

run : mvn clean install

2. change to the ProjectSubC

run : mvn test

Comment: During mvn clean install, it;s falling because of Junit failure. Do you want me to suppress test? i mean mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true?

Comment: I have tried what you have mentioned. But no luck still the same output

Comment: cd ProjectSubA and run mvn clean package install.  Then cd ProjectSubB still run mvn clean package install , at last cd ProjectSubC run mvn clean test

Answer (score 0):

To ignore test in project A , B :
1.In parent pom

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19</version> 
 </plugin>
```

2.In pom (A and B)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And at parent-pom : mvn clean test