# Run JUnit tests for Maven reactor nested sub-sub-module

Tags: maven, junit

I'm working with a [deeply nested Maven reactor project](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/dspace-5.4):

- root `pom.xml` specifies a module `dspace`
- module `dspace`'s `pom.xml` specifies a module `modules`
- module `modules`'s `pom.xml` specifies (among others) a module `rest`

So there is a nested module hierarchy: `dspace -> modules -> rest`.

I have written JUnit tests for (sub-sub-)module `rest` and would like to execute them. If I run `mvn test -pl rest`, Maven fails:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: rest @
[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: rest -> [Help 1]
```

How can I execute tests in nested Maven modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy: `mvn test -pl dspace/modules/rest`

(or when tests are deactivated by default, as it is the case with the example DSpace Maven project: `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=false test -pl dspace/modules/rest` )

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for my multi module maven application. I am able to run the JUnit test case from root directory by issuing the below maven command. My Multi module project structure is something like this.

- Custom-Service (Parent Module)

  - Model-API     (Sub-Module)
  - Model-Impl    (Sub-Module)
  - WebServices   (Sub-Module)

I want to run JUnit test case inside ***Model-Impl*** module.

mvn -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=MyTest clean install -pl Model-Impl -am